# Textbox not showing output in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to show a output in textbox in MVC. But its not displaying anything. I used the following code and i attached screenshot below:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(up => up.CompileOutput)

foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
            {

               userProgram.CompileOutput  = "Line number " + CompErr.Line +
                            ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber +
                            ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";" +
                            Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
            }

return View(userProgram);
```

[image: output]

[image: error]

The first image shows that the output is binded with that particular textbox. But in browser (image 2) shows nothing in the textbox (red colour)

Comment: please do not ask the same question twice. the detected duplicate of @verikon is your own post.

Answer (score 0):

I am even wondering why you did not got an exception. `return view(string)` will look for a view with the string parameter as name, it will not show the text.

I would suggest you use `ViewBag` instead. So you set your error text in a property you name as follow:

```
foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
{
    userProgram.CompileOutput  = "Line number " + CompErr.Line +
                                 ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber +
                                 ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";" +
                                 Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
}

ViewBag.ErrorText = userProgram.CompileOutput;
```

You can later on retrieve the value by simply calling `ViewBag.ErrorText` from you Razor view

Comment: Its not working Dhaou

Answer (score 0):

Why not try doing it another way?

`@Html.TextArea("CompileOutput", userProgram.CompileOutput)`